# Django models get_fields() but not reverse relations

Tags: django-models

The `get_fields()` [function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/meta/#retrieving-all-field-instances-of-a-model) on the `Meta` object returns reverse relations. What is the best way to filter these?

I can see the `_get_fields()` [function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/_modules/django/db/models/options/#Options.get_fields) has a `reverse` parameter, but this is not exposed to a public API.